# Unable to download Sql Server from Microsoft

Tags: sql-server, download, installation

i'm trying to download Sql 2012 from microsoft official website but each time i hit the "Next" buttton. 
[image]

and this take me to this page 
[image]

But nothing happens and this loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

On the second screen you can see line. "If your download does not start after 30 second Click here". So click there and download and your problem will disappear.

Comment: wojtaszek if i click on "Click Here" it take me to the first image i have paste . where i try again and then again on second page

Comment: try to change browser. MS page works, and allow to download these files.